# Delphi y DataSnap para ANDROID

Tags: android, delphi

Tengo un programa que a través del componente TDSClientCallBackChannelManager gestiona unos mensajes a través de un servidor DATASNAP. Quiero hacerlo para ANDROID e IOS, y el primer problema es que  me dice en el Uses que DataSnap.DsSession no existe en ANDROID y supongo que tampoco en IOS. Alguna respuesta.

Gracias

**En la zona de Interface utilizo:**

```
type
  TMyCallback = class(TDBXCallback)
  public
    function Execute(const Arg: TJSONValue): TJSONValue; override;
  end;
```

**Ya en Implementación la funcion es:**

```
function TMyCallback.Execute(const Arg: TJSONValue): TJSONValue;
begin
  PanelForm.QueueLogMsg(Arg.ToString);
  Result := TJSONTrue.Create;
end;
```

**Después de conectar con el Servidor de DataSnap, se utiliza estas instrucciones que las tengo en el FormShow:**

```
DSClientCallbackChannelManager1.ManagerId := TDSTunnelSession.GenerateSessionId;
  FMyCallbackName                           := TDSTunnelSession.GenerateSessionId;
  DSClientCallbackChannelManager1.RegisterCallback(FMyCallbackName,TMyCallback.Create);
  LocalClientId   := DSClientCallbackChannelManager1.ManagerId;
 

  LocalCallbackId := FMyCallbackName;
```

A DataSnap.DsSession pertenece TDSTunnelSession.

Funciona bien en Windows, pero en ANDROID me dice que mo existe esa libreria.

Answer (score 1):

Tras hacer pruebas, esto funciona para ANDROID:

```
DSClientCallbackChannelManager1.ManagerId := TDSSessionHelper.GenerateSessionId; 
FMyCallbackName                           := TDSSessionHelper.GenerateSessionId;
```

Hace lo mismo, pero en vez de depender de DataSnap.DSSession, que no soporta ANDROID, depende de Datasnap.DSCommon que no presenta problema.